# How to get sessions formed by google fit?

Tags: android, google-fit

How to get sessions formed by google fit app?
I want to show in my android app something like this:

[image]

May I make it by session api or google fit don't save sessions?

Comment: Does Google fit save sessions made yourself?

Comment: not sure, I'm not familiar with google-fit. just thought more detail would help people answer

Answer (score 0):

[**Record Fitness Data**](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/record)

You can use either [Recording API](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/record) or [Sessions API](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/using-sessions).

> **Sessions API**
>
> The Sessions API enables your app to create sessions in the fitness store using real time data or data you previously collected using the Sensors API or outside Google Fit.
>
> **Recording API**
>
> enables your app to request automated storage of sensor data in a battery- efficient manner by creating subscriptions. A subscription is associated with an Android app and consists of a fitness data type or a specific data source.

NOTE:

> The recorded data is available in the user's fitness history. If you also want to show the data in your app in real time, you need to use the Sensors API together with the Recording API. To record fitness data with session metadata, you can use the Sessions API.